# Formula Excel 2016

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I will be the coordinator of a racing event for approximately 200 children.  There will be approximately 20 races each having a first, second and third place winner. Children will be pre-registered and must submitted their personal information. First name, last name, age, sex, and address. Each athlete will be assigned an Athletes Number. Volunteers can not have access to the personal information.

Sheet 1 contain two columns. Column A is labeled EVENT. Column B is labelled ATHLETES NUMBER. Scorekeepers will enter the winning athletes number for each event in Column B.

Sheet 2 is xx columns. Column A- EVENT, Column B -ATHLETES NUMBER, Column C-First Name,Column D-Last Name, Column E-Age, Column F-Sex, Column F-Address

Sheet 3 is the database which contains the athletes' personal information and is 6 columns. Column A is labeled ATHLETES NUMBER, Column B is FIRST NAME, Column C is LAST NAME, Column D is AGE, Column E is SEX, Column F is ADDRESS.

I need a formula(s?) for Sheet 3 that will look at the winning athletes number in sheet1 and return the all personal information found in sheet2 in column A to F.  Or is there an easier way to approach this?  Thank you so much for any help you can give!

Comment: There are many LOOKUP type functions, just a matter of putting them in the cells and referencing the correct data.

Comment: This community is not a scripting service. Tell us what have you tried.

Comment: I think you need a VLOOKUP formula, its fairly complex to understand but once you get the hang off it, it is incredible useful. I suggest you look into it a bit, give it a try and then come back and edit this question or ask a new question when you face problems. Be specific and give sample data plus your expected outcome.

Comment: It's great that you're volunteering to help out at a neighborhood kid's activity.  You might be a novice Excel user, and I'll give you a hint to get you started.  Type this in cell A2 of Sheet 3 (assumes A1 contains "Athlete's Number"):  =VLOOKUP(Sheet1!$B2,Sheet2!$B$2:$G$nnn,1,FALSE).  Here nnn is the last row of your lookup table on Sheet 2.  That should put the first Athlete's Number in A2 of Sheet 3.  If you fill the formula down, you should get all the other Athlete Numbers.  And you should be able to figure out how to get all the other columns that you need.

Comment: The only tricky part is that the Athlete's Number column on Sheet 2 must be sorted into ascending order for the VLOOKUP function to work correctly.  As @Kevin said, check back here if you run into problems.  We'll be glad to help.